# Loop script until file has equal size for a minute

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, exists

I have cronjob to run a script every day in specific time. The script is for conversion a large file (about 2GB) in specific folder. The problem is that not every day my coleague put the file in the folder before the time, written as cronjob.

Please help me to add commands in the script or to write second script for:

1. Check if the file exists in the folder.
2. If the previous action is true, check the file size every minute. (I would like to avoid conversion of still incomming large file).
3. If filesize stays unchanged for 2 minutes, start the script for conversion.

I give you the important lines of the script so far:

```
cd /path-to-folder
for $i in *.mpg; do avconv -i "$i" "out-$i.mp4" ; done
```

10x for the help!

**NEW CODE AFTER COMMENTS:**

There is file in the folder!

```
#! /bin/bash


cdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)
dump="/path/folder1"
base=$(ls "$dump")

if [ -n "$file"]
then
    file="$dump/$base"
    size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")
    count=0
    while sleep 10
    do
        size0=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")
        if [ $size=$size0 ]
        then $((count++))
             count=0
        fi
        if [ $count = 2 ]
        then break
        fi
    done
    # file has been stable for two minutes. Start conversion.

CONVERSION CODE

fi
```

MESSAGE IN TERMINAL: Maybe error???

```
script.sh: 17: script.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "count++"
```

Comment: FYI: for me, using `bash` 3.2, the command sequence `count=0; : $((count++)); echo $count; ((count++)); echo $count $(($count+3)) $((count+3))` echoes 1, 2, 5, 5. That is, both notations work. One possibility is that you aren't using `bash` after all — normally, the shebang doesn't use a space, but I'm not sure whether that matters. You do have a problem at `if [ $size=$size0 ]`; you must separate the arguments in a test: `if [ $size = $size0 ]`.  That doesn't explain the reported error. You seem to be missing an `else` clause. You probably need to use `: $((count++))` in the `then` clause.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Below I have added new answer with working code thanks to your help. I have final question about the right way to loop the script if the file exists. Please see answer 2 when you have the time. 10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally made some working code as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)
folder1="/path-to-folder1"

cd $folder1

while file=$(ls "$folder1")
      [ -z "$file" ]
do sleep 5 && echo "There in no file in the folder at $cdate."
done

echo "There is a file in folder at $cdate"
size1=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")
echo "The size1 is $size1 at $cdate"
size2=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")
echo "The size2 is $size2 at $cdate"
if [ $size1 = $size2 ]
then
echo "file is stable at $cdate. Do conversion."
```

#### Is the next line the right one to loop the same script???

```
else sh /home/user/bin/exist-stable.sh
fi
```

#### The right code after comments below is

```
else exec /home/user/bin/exist-stable.sh
fi
```

Comment: _Is the next line the right way to loop the script?_  Answer: No.  It runs the script again, but without completing the first, so you'll eventually run out of processes.  At a pinch, you could use `exec /home/user/bin/exist-stable.sh` instead; that replaces the current process with a new one that reruns the script.  It would probably be more conventional just to wrap an extra `while true; do ...; done` loop around the existing loop and the actions that follow it.  (Or you could pause between iteratations: `while sleep 15; do ...; done`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried the "while" way with the difference between $size2 and $size1. It was something like: `while [ $size1 = $size2 ] do script.sh done` but something was not right. The script loops even if the file existed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler also I have to make sure that the processes for filesize will run again if there is file in folder. That's why I need loop to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
file=/work/daily/dump/name_of_dump_file

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    # size=$(ls -l "$file" | awk '{print $5}')
    size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")
    count=0
    while sleep 60
    do
        size0=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")
        if [ $size = $size0 ]
        then : $((count++))
        else size=$size0
             count=0
        fi
        if [ $count = 2 ]
        then break
        fi
    done
    # File has been stable for 2 minutes — start conversion
fi
```

---

Given the slightly revised requirements (described in the comments), and assuming that the file names do not contain spaces or newlines or other similarly awkward characters, then you can use:

```
dump="/work/daily/dump"                 # folder 1
base=$(ls "$dump")

if [ -n "$file" ]
then
    file="$dump/$base"
    ...code as before...
    # File has been stable for 2 minutes - start conversion
    dir2="/work/daily/conversion"       # folder 2
    file2="$dir2/$(basename $base .mpg).xyz"
    convert -i "$file" -o "$file2"
    mv "$file" "/work/daily/originals"  # folder 3
    ncftpput other.coast.example.com /work/daily/input "$file2"
    mv "$file2" "/work/daily/converted" # folder 4
fi
```

If there's nothing in the folder, the process exits.  If you want it to wait until there is a file to convert, then you need a loop around the file test:

```
while file=$(ls "$dump")
      [ -z "$file" ]
do sleep 60
done
```

This uses a little-known feature of shell loops; you can stack the commands in the control, but it is the exit status of the last one that controls the loop.

Comment: Note that this solution will work in Linux, but in other operating systems, `stat` may use different options.  In FreeBSD and OSX, for example, you need to use use `stat -f '%z' "$file"` to set the `size` variable.  Also, it's generally preferred to use bash's built-in `[[` operator for `if` instead of the old Bourne `/bin/[`. Better performance, better habits.

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu 12.04 but do I have to put commands in the convertion script right after the row `# File has been stable for 2 minutes — start conversion`  or I have to write a command to run the other script?

Comment: @ispasov - you can do whatever you like, either add commands to this code or have it call an external code.  Since you didn't post any code in your question, Jonathan wasn't really able to address your specific requirements in the script excerpt he posted.  His answer definitely addresses what you posted in your question.

Comment: @ghoti - I gave two of important lines of the code up in my question. Could you help me by putting my code into Jonathan's one? 10x :)

Comment: You added the code fragment 45 minutes after I posted the answer I gave.  It is not clear from the fragment you've given which of the `.mpg` files you are concerned about changing.  You need to take the ideas from the answer script and apply them to your situation.  We provide help; we try not to babysit people.

Comment: @ghoti, `[` is a bash builtin -- `type -a [`

Comment: @glennjackman - wow, right you are. I distinctly remember a time when `[` was *not* a built-in for bash, but that was a long time ago, and I guess I never re-learned that bit. :-P  So much for the performance argument!

Comment: @ghoti: you're dating yourself — it has been a built-in in the Bourne shell since System V for sure, and I think even System III.  There is still, typically, a separate executable `/bin/test` linked to `/bin/[` that can be used, but the shells themselves do not use it.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll try the proposed solution today and I'll give feedback. I am new to this site and promise to ask more specificly next time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So I have a problem. Every time the name of the file that I receive in that folder is different, so I can't define variable $file. I only know the extension of the file - .mpg. I can't rename incomming lange file bacause I will break the process. What should I do now?

Comment: Define the problem more carefully.  What do you know?  What will be the case in the steady state?  What will be the case when you first apply this script?  If you need to look at all the files, maybe you need to generate a list of files that have a last modification time older than two minutes ago.  The `touch` command can be used to create a marker file with the correct time stamp, and (GNU) `find` can be used to find files older than that (or you can use `bash`'s `-ot` test).  Those files are eligible to be moved to their next (final?) resting place.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Here is the whole process: folder1 and folder2 are empty -> file1 apears in folder1 -> convert file1 to file2 into folder2 -> send file2 via ftp -> move file1 in folder3 -> move file2 in folder4 -> folder1 and folder2 are empty again. So in folder1 there is only one file during process. The script has only to establish that file in folder1 exists but because the file is between 2GB and 15GB the conversion has to start only when the filesize is stable for 2 minutes. Otherwise the script has to sleep 2 minutes and loop until file is stable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I managed to create the script that I described in my previous comment but I need customization of the beguinning, because I don't know the filename. I know only the approximate time of the start of the filetrasfer to folder1. I don't know when the filetranfer finishes to start the conversion. That is why I need loop and filesize comparison. I really appresiate your help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have added your second code and put your first code in it as you wrote in edition of your first answer. And I have a message in the terminal: `script.sh: 17: script.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "count++"`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The above message appears no matter if there is or there isn't file in the folder.

Comment: The use of `: $((count++))` prevent error messages because `:` mean `true` and ignore arguments. That work, but instead you could write simply: `((count++))`  without `true` or `:` **and** without sign `$`.